# What is the term to describe when pressure exerted between two obejcts is balanced?

Tags: forces, pressure, terminology

I'm searching for a term here.

All materials compress (some more than others).

Newton's Third law [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton%27s_third_law):

> ...all forces between two objects exist in equal magnitude and opposite direction: if one object A exerts a force FA on a second object B, then B simultaneously exerts a force FB on A, and the two forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction: FA = −FB

So for example, if a rubber ball is placed on top of a sponge, both would feel a "constant" force exerted on each other (in this case due to gravity). Now obviously the sponge would compress more, while the rubber ball would hardly compress.

**What is the term to denote that the force applied by and to each of these objects results in a balance of compression?**

I'm not even sure if balance is the right word to describe this. I'm trying to describe that the compression of each object will no longer increase or decrease. The closest term I conjured up was "equilibrium of pressure."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (when total force on an object or interface is zero, such that there is no net motion) is just called "mechanical equilibrium."

Answer (score 0):

Newton’s third law does not tell us what the effect of the equal and opposite forces are on each of the bodies. Newton’s second law applied to each of the bodies individually tells us what, if any, acceleration each experiences based on the net external force applied to each. Mechanics of deformable solids helps us to determine the deformation each body experiences as a result of the same force each experiences.

Hope this helps